# Python class __str__ return only one line dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

beginning to learn python, so sorry if this is elementary. 
I want to use `__str__()` to print all pairs from a dictionary, which is an instance attribute of my class.

I do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Node:

    nextindex = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.targetnode = defaultdict(Node)
        self.index = Node.nextindex
        Node.nextindex += 1

    def add(self, line, pos=0):
        if pos == len(line):
            self.targetnode[""] = None
        else:
            c = line[pos]
            self.targetnode[c].add(line, pos+1)

    def __str__(self):
        for c, tnode in self.targetnode.items():
            return "Node %d Alphabet %s Targetnode %d" % (self.index, c, tnode.index)


root = Node()

for line in file:
    root.add(line)

print(root)
```

The `file`contains a list of words, one word per line, just like:

```
her
his
here
```

What I expected:

```
Node 0 Alphabet h Targetnode 1
Node 1 Alphabet e Targetnode 2
Node 2 Alphabet l Targetnode 3
```

etc.

What I really got:

```
Node 0 Alphabet h Targetnode 1
```

(h is the first alphabet from my wordlist)

Could someone please tell me why did it only return one line back? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are returning the `__str__()` in for loop. Once return statement is executed. You are no longer in that function. Your first loop is executed and returned.

Comment: Oh yes, I've also tried return after the loop and use a list to collect the info that I need -> then return this list, but it gives me the same thing back :( What should I do?

Comment: Where is `file` variable defined. What is the content of `file` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh it's a list of word, one word per line just like: his, her, here etc.

Comment: can you add that file to the question

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Done :)

Comment: `self.targetnode.` looks like a tree, what kind of traversal are you looking for here?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh yes, I iterate over the defaultdict to create the tree structure

Comment: your `__str__` implementation doesn't do the traversal,

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Can't I do this in add()?

Comment: Yes, you can constructor your string as you add, and return it in `__str__`, and I would suggest redesigning whatever you are trying here to make your `__str__` more robust

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Answer (score 0):

You need to return after the loop, or use `str.join`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '\n'.join([
        'Node %d Alphabet %s Targetnode %d'
        % (self.index, c, tnode.index)
        for c, tnode in self.targetnode.items()
    ])
```

If you don’t want to have each one separated by a newline, change the `'\n'` to, say, a comma `', '`

Comment: @N Chauhan I've also tried return after the loop and use a list to collect the info that I need -> then return this list, but it gives me the same thing back :(

Comment: What are the values of `self.index` and `self.targetnode`?

Comment: ```self.index``` is the "name" of the node, e.g. 0, 1, 2.. ```self.targetnode``` is a defaultdict(), which key = a alphabet (an edge), value = next Node

Comment: I don't think so. The number of loop should be same as the number of pairs in dictionary I think